# $G\in (L_p)^*$ such that $G(f) = 0$ for any $f\in L_p$ such that supp$f \subset X\setminus X_0$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

> Let $G$ be a bounded functional linear on $L_p$ and suppose that exists a measurable $X_0$ such that for any measurable $E\subset X\setminus X_0$ with $\mu(E)<+\infty$ we have $G(\chi_E)=0.$ Given $f \in L_p$ such that $\{x: f(x)\neq 0\} \subset X\setminus X_0$, prove that $G(f) = 0$.

I wrote the following proof:

We first suppose that $f\in L_p$ is only real valued (i.e, we don't have $f=\infty)$. We may write $f^+ = \lim_n \varphi_n$ for an increasing sequence of simple functions, where $\varphi_n = \sum_k  c_{n,k}\chi_{F_{n,k}}$. Since $0 \leq \varphi_n \leq f$ and $f$ is finite, we get that $\mu(F_{n,k})<\infty$ for all values of $n,k$. If $[f\neq 0] \subset X\setminus X_0$, for large values of $n$ we get that $F_{n,k}\subset X\setminus X_0$ and hence $G(\chi_{F_{n,k}}) = 0.$ Since $G$ is continuous (it is bounded), it follows for large values of $n$ that

$$G(f^+) = \lim G(\varphi_n) = \lim \sum_kc_{n,k} G(\chi_{F_{n,k}}) = 0 $$

Similarly $G(f^-) = 0$ and hence $G(f) = G(f^+)-G(f^-) = 0$.

Questions: 1) Is the above proof correct? 2) What to do when $f$ can take infinite values?

**Edit:** Ive checked on my book that by definition we dont consider infinite valued functions in $L_p$. So, now I just want to check if the above proof is correct

Comment: you dont need the assumption that $f<\infty $ because $\mu (F_{n,k})<\infty $ necessarily, otherwise $f^+\notin L^p$. Or an easier argument: if $\varphi $ is a simple function then, by definition, each $F_{n,k}$ have finite measure

Comment: if $G(\chi _E)=0$ then, by linearity, $G(\varphi _n)=0$ for each $n$, and by continuity of $G$ then $G(f)=0$